# How to format output result of Google Maps API Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi i am try change output result like neighborhood, city and country. My intention is that when the user enter his address he returns only the street.

Example of data i want to remove.
[image]

This my script of Google Maps API.

```
 <script>
    function initAutocomplete() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
          lat: -23.69389,
          lng: -46.565
        },
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
          lat: 34.3630003,
          lng: -84.332207
        },
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        draggable: true
      });

      var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('pac-input'));

      google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function () {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var i, place;

        for (i = 0; place = places[i]; i++) {
          bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
          marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
        }

        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        map.setZoom(14);
      });
    }

    var map = document.getElementById("map");
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initAutocomplete);
  </script>
```

This my search-box.

```
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">home</i>
      <input placeholder="Defina um endereço para seu fornecedor" id="pac-input" name="addressRouteTransporter" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="addressRouteTransporter">Endereço:</label>
    </div>
```

Thanks for help xD

Comment: Are you referring to changing what you want to display after clicking on an autocomplete suggestion?

Comment: @henrisycip after clicking of suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use-case is actually better suited for using the Places Autocomplete feature instead of the Places SearchBox. What you'll do is filter through the selected place's `address_components` array and only get the likes of `route` or `premise` etc, which are what the "address" is made of.
Ex:

```
componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  sublocality_level_1: 'long_name',
  premise: 'long_name'
};
```

Then simply replace the value of the input field to the combination of your chosen components. 
`inputField.value = addressString;`

I recommend to read more about it here:

- [Google sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) Be sure to pay attention to the warning in the doc about

> "You may need to select different components to align with the postal
>   address formats of different countries."

- [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#address_forms)

I also want to mention the code you provided is very incomplete and I tried to create a minimal, verifiable, complete example out of it to show you the basics of how to use the Autocomplete and address components.

Working jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/yy3p7hh9/1/

Attached code snippet below:

```js
var autocomplete, 
marker, 
map,
inputField = document.getElementById('pac-input'),
// this is the type of address components you would like to get. You will filter through this object and
// check if the place result has any 1 of these address components. 
// Notice how type 'locality' will not be retrieved so big, general places without these properties will not
// show
componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  sublocality_level_1: 'long_name',
  premise: 'long_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -23.69389,
      lng: -46.565
    },
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: 34.3630003,
      lng: -84.332207
    },
    map: map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    draggable: true
  });

  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
    (inputField), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });

  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
  // fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var addressString = '';

  if (place.geometry) {
    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
  // warning this only gets the first type of the component. E.g. 'sublocality_level_1'
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      addressString += ' ' + val + ',';
    }
  }
  // just remove the last comma
  addressString = addressString.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
  inputField.value = addressString;
  console.log(addressString);
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  map.setZoom(14);
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-field col s6">
  <i class="material-icons prefix">home</i>
  <input placeholder="Defina um endereço para seu fornecedor" id="pac-input" name="addressRouteTransporter" type="text" class="validate">
  <label for="addressRouteTransporter">Endereço:</label>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCD0rWgXRVBa7PgaTWXVp_gU51pgHGviYY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

Comment: work perfect, i can extend the functionalities? example add postal code output in input-field?

Comment: Of course! Keep reading the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#address_forms) about it and you'll see you can simply add/remove properties from the `componentForm` to see what you'd like to get out of the resulting place. Then it's a matter of appending the string to the input field.